# Rolling month average in power bi dax

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have these two columns:
SALES_CALLSID 
QFQ4TA5006C2 
QZPIOA18LW8A 
QS4GSA300PU0
....; and
MEETING_DATE 
7/10/2014 12:00 
3/27/2015 12:00 
11/3/2015 12:00

I need the count of the first column (salesid) but this count should be a trailing twelve month average for every month, i.e. for example for July- the count of sales id of july + count of last 11 months (i.e. based on the meeting date column), similarly this measure has to be made for every other month.

The "Sales Call ID" column is a text field. I can see the count using the formula COUNTA(AccountSalesCalls[SALES_CALLSID])`.

The formula i built to get the total count of sales id for last 12 months is as follows:

```
CALCULATE (
    COUNTA ( AccountSalesCalls[SALES_CALLSID] ),
    DATESBETWEEN (
        AccountSalesCalls[MEETING_DATE],
        NEXTDAY ( SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR ( LASTDATE ( AccountSalesCalls[MEETING_DATE] ) ) ),
        LASTDATE ( AccountSalesCalls[MEETING_DATE] )
    )
)
```

When i do this i get an error:

> A date column containing duplicate dates was specified in the call to
>   function 'DATESBETWEEN'. This is not supported.

I then built a DATE table and replaced MEETING_DATE column with column in DATE table as follows:

```
CALCULATE (
    COUNTA ( AccountSalesCalls[SALES_CALLSID] ),
    DATESBETWEEN (
        'Date'[Date],
        NEXTDAY ( SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR ( LASTDATE ( AccountSalesCalls[MEETING_DATE] ) ) ),
        LASTDATE ( AccountSalesCalls[MEETING_DATE] )
    )
)
```

This just gives me the count of that month which is the same result as `COUNTA(AccountSalesCalls[SALES_CALLSID])`.

I still haven't done the division part to get the average but first wanted to figure out how to make the total count work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A simple and representative sample of your data could be useful in order to provide an answer or some guidance

Comment: ok, so i have these two columns:SALES_CALLSID
QFQ4TA5006C2
QZPIOA18LW8A
QS4GSA300PU0

; and, MEETING_DATE
7/10/2014 12:00
3/27/2015 12:00
11/3/2015 12:00                                                                                          i need the count of the first column (salesid) but this count should be a trailing twelve month average for every month, i.e. for example for July- the count of sales id of july + count of last 11 months (i.e. based on the meeting date column), similarly this measure has to be made for every other month...i hope this clarifies...

Comment: sorry i coudn't represent the information in column form, but its just two columns- 1.SALES_CALLSID followed by sample three values and then, 2. MEETING_DATE followed by sample three values...

Comment: Edit your initial question, Check this [How to edit your question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work)

Comment: Done, hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

You were nearly there.

The calculated column:

```
Average = CALCULATE (
  COUNTA ( AccountSalesCalls[SALES_CALLSID] ) / 12,
  DATESBETWEEN(
    AccountSalesCalls[MEETING_DATE],
    DATEADD(AccountSalesCalls[MEETING_DATE], -12, MONTH),
    AccountSalesCalls[MEETING_DATE]
  ),
  ALL(AccountSalesCalls)
)
```

Note this divides by a constant (12), which would be incorrect for the first year of your data. You will have to decide how to deal with this (if at all).

One option could be to divide by the date range of existing selected data instead:

```
Average = CALCULATE (
  COUNTA ( AccountSalesCalls[SALES_CALLSID] ) / 
    DATEDIFF( MIN(AccountSalesCalls[MEETING_DATE] ),
      MAX( AccountSalesCalls[MEETING_DATE] ),MONTH),
  DATESBETWEEN(...
```

[More or moving averages using DAX](https://javierguillen.wordpress.com/2011/09/13/calculating-moving-averages-in-powerpivot-dax/)

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Comment: I just slightly modified op's formula - not sure what else there was to add. Tried this, worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of dividing by 12, I have seen Rob Collie handle the division by

COUNTROWS ( VALUES ( 'Date'[Year-Month] ) )

where [Year-Month] is a calculated column in the 'Date' table:

= FORMAT ( 'Date'[Date], "YYYY-mm" )

Using VALUES in this way also handles cases where the available data covers less than 12 months.

I have also seen Chandoo use a similar approach, but using the COUNTROWS to check if there are twelve months available to base the rolling average on (and if not, return blank).