# Average Power BI Aggregates

Tags: powerbi

I have entries that are uniquely identified by a variety of fields and that I pull in from Excel. Entries relate to the daily amount of work done, and people working on a specific area of a plant. Each entry has a work done field (measurement of the work done on that area), and a manpower count. The productivity per area is calculated by work done divided by manpower.

```
Date          Area    Work Done    Manpower    Productivity
2017/02/01    Pipe    50           25          2
2017/02/01    Valve   22           2           11
2017/02/01    Machine 54           2           22
```

I want to display the work done and manpower as bars in power BI, and the average productivity per day as a line. The problem is that the real productivity for the day (total work done divided by total manpower) is not the average of the individual productivity per area. Thus, I want to be able to create a line that total work done and manpower per day, and divides them to get the productivity, then only displays the productivity.

How can I do this in power BI?

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question entirely, but you can try replacing your `Productivity` column with a measure `Productivity = SUM([Work Done])/SUM([Manpower])`.

Comment: You did! Thank you! Follow-up, is there a way of specifying that a measure only apply over a specified time period. For example, the average of a variable over the last three week?

Comment: No problem - glad to help. Sure, it's possible, take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38774048/rolling-month-average-in-power-bi-dax/39368348#39368348

Comment: @user5226582 You should consider placing that as an answer so OP can accept, and investigate his followup question separately.