# Power BI - Can I have custom aggregation function within chart?

Tags: powerbi

I have (last) two days of experience working with Power BI so it is possible that the answer is obvious. The table in my dataset has following format.

[image]

Note that we have `Total Requests` and `Successful Requests` values for each combination of `Date`, `Client ID` and `API method`. The `Success Rate` table column values are calculated by dividing `Successful Requests` values by `Total Requests` values.

Now I have created a report from the table as below.

[image]

I have set `Date` column as X-axis and `Success Rate` as the value of the bar chart. Additionally, I have added two slicers one each for `API method` and `Client ID`  columns.

The aggregate function for values is selected as 'Average'. But this gives result `(0.1 + 0.2 + 0.3 + 0.4) / 4 = 0.25` as `Success Rate` for date of June 25. I instead need it to be `Sum(Successful Requests on June 25) / Sum(Total Requests on June 25)` i.e. `4321 / 11110 = 0.39` as `Success Rate` displayed.

Also, if user selects fields in either or both slicers, similar calculation should take place for the subset of data selected through slicers.

How do I achieve it? One way is to have 8 copies of the same table, each grouped by different combinations of the three columns. This might be an overkill for the simple problem. Also, I do not know if it is possible to make slicing work by picking one of the many tables on the fly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42364341/average-power-bi-aggregates?rq=1#comment71883037_42364341). Instead of having a table column for `Success Rate`, I created a [measure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44745239/power-bi-can-i-have-custom-aggregation-function-within-chart) in report as `Success Rate = SUM('Success Rate'[Successful Requests]) / Sum('Success Rate'[Total Requests])`.